# track email with googleusercontents img resource and redirecting to my website

Tags: html, email, url

I'm using email tracking services of some email sender company. It is achieved through requesting img resource when opening email. Here is the code inserted into HTML message:

`<img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/TObr7aARe70s=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.mywebsite.com/TrackEmail?j=eyJ1IjoiMQ4In0%3D&amp;r=0.614693022798747.gif" width="2" height="1">`

I'm interested in how eventually the request will come to my website and what exactly will be requested from my website - image or simple request? Can anyone please explain me? I think the magic is somewhere in this part `...d-e1-ft#htt....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a  tag with an src pointing to a script on your website that handles te request, get the information you wanna track and returns an invisible image (1x1 transparent pixel for example).

**Be careful with the googleusercontent cache servers**, they can break your tracking, take a look at this:

http://www.emailmarketingtipps.de/2013/12/07/gmails-image-caching-affects-email-marketing-heal-opens-tracking/

This explains how to avoid caching using P3P headers and returning a Content-Type different to image/*